# Invalid syntax---python

Tags: python, syntax

I can't figure out why it is saying invalid syntax for the word Options in all of my If statements

```
Options = raw_input("Would you like to Square, Cube, Multiply, or Divide?    ")

If  Options == "Square" or Options == "square":
Square = int(raw_input("What number would you like to Square?    "))
Answer1 = Square ** 2
print "The answer is :%d" %Answer1

if Options == "Cube":
Cube = int(raw_input("What number would you like to Cube    "))
Answer2 = Cube ** 3
print "The answer is :%d" %Answer2

if Options == "Multiply":
Multiply1 = int(raw_input("What is the first number to multiply?    "))
Multiply2 = int(raw_input("What is the second number to multiply?     "))
Answer3 = Multiply1 * Multiply2
 print "The answer is :d%" %Answer3"
```

Comment: Reading a basic Python tutorial would be helpful here

Comment: The interrupter points to exactly where the error is located. Take advantage of this feature.

Answer (score 7):

Python is case-sensitive. `If` needs to be `if`. Your code also needs to be indented properly.

Comment: Python is also white space sensitive so press tab once under each if.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have it properly indented on my version but it was saying i had to do a certain way to post my question so i just changed it.

Comment: To post code in a question, copy and paste it from your editor, highlight it, and hit the code formatting button. Don't remove formatting, especially for Python code.