# Python invalid syntax questions

Tags: python

Why does the code below return the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

If(amount_paid==12):

I know it's basic but just starting out learning Python in Visual Studio Code

Thanks for any help,

Phil

Comment: Python is case sensitive

Comment: @Nick almost certainly... i can't find a good duplicate at the moment, but I'm on my phone so please feel free to offer up a good one

Comment: Fixed! Sorry, didn't notice the upper Case I in the if keyword, thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid syntax---python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783185/invalid-syntax-python)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga there's a couple there now

Answer (score 4):

Most things in Python are case-sensitive. Here, that's the `if` construct -- `If amount_paid == 12:` is not well formed, but `if amount_paid == 12:` is.

Comment: python, in general, is case-sensitive.

Comment: Good point, will edit my answer.

Comment: Fixed! Sorry, didn't notice the upper Case I in the if keyword, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try making `If` lowercase (make the "I" lowercase)

Comment: Fixed! Sorry, didn't notice the upper Case I in the if keyword, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. The issue in the upper case "If". Change to "if"
2. Parentheses are not mandatory, although, they should not affect anything in your case: `if amount_paid == 12:`